# Developer account at EU6 not running tests

Tags: unit-test

I'm playing around with a developer account and for some reason the test execution either takes long or doesn't work. Twenty minutes ago i ran a test on the following code, and so far it hasn't finished:

```
@istest
public class Sometest {
}
```

Obviously this isn't due to code complexity. There are no other tests in the developer account worth mentioning. I had the same problem last night. Am i unaware of some developer account restrictions? Is this perhaps normal for a developer account? Trust.salesforce.com doesn't mention anything. I'd love your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing to run in that test so nothing to execute.

While there may also be some issue on that pod try using this as the test

```
@isTest
private class myExampleTest{

     private static tstmethod void firstExample(){

          system.assertEquals(true,true,'Something funny happened');

     }

}
```

And, no there are no special restrictions on the developer account with regards to test methods.

Comment: Intriguing, your code does work. Must be my code than that causes this. I have never seen test code take forever instead of just failing or not running in the first place. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @Kasper It could have the status of not started or something else since there is no code to run in your example. Also, I see you are new here and wanted to let you know that if an answer solved your question common practice it to mark it as accepted by checking the checkmark. This allows others looking for a similar question to find answers.

Comment: The above code wasn't really what i was trying to test. I tried that code  to see if it wasn't just my actual code being odd. Apparently i should have put a bit more effort into the above code ;). Now i'll know to start looking for the oddity in my actual code, but i have clue to what that may be.